# How to logout user in Laravel functional tests?

Tags: laravel, authentication, testing, mocking

In Laravel feature tests,

Given that user has been programmatically logged in using

```
$this->actingAs(self::$user, 'api');
```

How would I logout this user?
actingAs does not accept null as first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to logout the user is

```
$guard = Mockery::mock(Guard::class);
$guard->expects('check')
        ->andReturns(false);

Auth::shouldReceive('guard')
       ->andReturns($guard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the guard you are using:

1. for `TokenGuard` you can use `Auth::forgetUser()`
2. for `SessionGuard` use `Auth::logout()`